# WKRefreshBackgroundTask only handled once per hour

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, background-process

I've written a Watchkit Extension (WatchOS 5.1.1) where I'm attempting to fetch data every 30 minutes or so.

I've read so far that the background task scheduling is not punctual by the minute, but pretty reliable to use couple times an hour.

I'm scheduling the task using

```
 WKExtension.shared().scheduleBackgroundRefresh(withPreferredDate: Date(timeIntervalSinceNow:  interval * 60 ), userInfo: ["time": Logger.getDateString()] as NSDictionary ) { (error: Error?) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error occured while scheduling background refresh: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
```

This works, however no matter what Intervall I chose, the task is only executed after around 60 minutes. I've written myself a log where I can see when

```
func handle(_ backgroundTasks: Set<WKRefreshBackgroundTask>)
```

is called in the ExtensionDelegate, and I can confirm that the handle is just called not often enough.

My Watch is on >80% batterie so that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Appreciate any input on this!

Comment: WatchOS 5.1.1 seems to have background update problems here.  5.1 was very consistent and was updating continuously, but 5.1.1 has been pretty bad...  So if you haven't tried on an earlier version maybe this is related.  I've been using it for complication updates for a long time now it it just got super reliable prior to 5.1.1.

Comment: Yeah, that actually might explain my issues, I think the behavior was better under 5.1, but wasn't sure. Overall, I'm massively struggeling with the whole topic, did you manage to create an App which does update the complication relaibly for days?

Comment: Still not working ok even if I use watchOS 6.1.